# Why are my elements losing position?

Tags: html, css

So here is my box:

[BOX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yqj9.png)

Ok, now I want to add box near the input of the BET box.

```
<div id="x2"></div> <!-- HTML --->
/* CSS */
#x2{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
```

The box after I add it:
[BOX-AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdhTq.png)

As you can see, it messed up the thin gray line and everything underneath it. I'm really not sure why.

HTML:

```
<div class="gamebox">
        <div id="bet-and-chance-texts">
            <p id="bettext">BET</p>
            <p id="profittext"><i class="fa fa-btc" aria-hidden="true"></i> PROFIT</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bet-and-chance-input-boxes">
            <input class="default" id="userbet" onkeyup="checkBet()" value="0.00000000" placeholder="BTC" name="bet" autocomplete="off">
            <div id="x2">x2</div>
            <input readonly class="default" id="profitinput" onkeyup="" value="100" placeholder="BTC" name="bet" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="line-separator"></div>
        <div id="button-texts">
            <p id="roll">ROLL UNDER</p>
            <p id="payout">PAYOUT</p>
            <p id="chance">CHANCE</p>
        </div>
        <div id="buttons">
            <input class="hidden-boxed-input-roll" value = "50.00"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" id="newpayout" onkeyup="calculateChance()" class="hidden-boxed-input" value = "2.000"/>
            <input autocomplete="off" id="newchance" onkeyup="checkChance()" class="hidden-boxed-input" value = "50"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div id="rolldice-section">
            <button type="button" id="dicebutton" onclick="prepareRoll(authToken);" style="vertical-align:middle"><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i> Roll dice</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
     .gamebox {
                height: auto;
                padding: 20px;
                width: 60%;
                font-family: Helvetica Neue;
                color: black;

                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-left: 20px;
                background-color: white;
            }
        .line-separator{
            height:.5px;
            background: lightgray;
            border-bottom:.5px solid lightgray;
        }
#x2{
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     background: cornflowerblue;
    float: left;
 }
input[class="default"]{
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E4ECF1;
    display: inline-block;
}
p[id="roll"]{
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
}

p[id="payout"]{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

p[id="chance"]{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 13px;
}
div[id=button-texts]{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Why does everything below the thin gray line get messed up? How can I solve this?

Comment: remove `float: left` to `#x2`and add `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
<div id="x2">x2</div>
```

to :

```
<span id="x2">x2</span>
```

since `div` have block display and you need to use `span` which is inline

then change your style, remove float and add some padding to #x2 :

```
#x2 {
   padding: 13px;
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   background: cornflowerblue;
}
```